# Why isn't Map subclassable in chrome/node?

Tags: javascript, v8, ecmascript-6

So ES 6 is bringing us [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (and none too soon). Wishing to subclass Map for my own nefarious purposes, I tried the following (abbreviated for clarity):

```
function Foo() {
    return Map.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
}

var bar = new Foo();
```

In V8 environments this throws an Error "Map constructor not called with 'new'". Why? SpiderMonkey gets this 'right':

```
Map.call({}, [['foo', 'bar']]).get('foo');
```

will, as expected, yield 'bar'. In both SpiderMonkey and V8 attempting something like

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype = new Map();
var bar = new Foo();
bar.set('foo', 'bar');
```

will fail: 'method set called on incompatible object'. So there goes that inheritance pattern. As far as I can tell from the [spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-map.prototype.has) (I don't have much spec-foo), actual Map objects have internal properties that are not accessible that are required for them to work properly. But why does V8 throw an error on the first pattern? This seems like an odd decision, especially when it works as expected in FF.

UPDATE: I noticed that FF and chrome both have `Object.setPrototypeOf` implemented. Just in case anyone stumbles across this and thinks of that, I can tell you it fails. Both of the following fail for different reasons:

```
//this totally fails, even for custom constructors/objects
var Foo = function(){};
Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo, Map.prototype);
var bar = new Foo(); //bar doesn't have any of the Map properties/methods

//this one has the methods but still throws the 'incompatible object'
//err. Also fails with new Map() instead of Map.prototype
var bar = Object.setPrototypeOf({}, Map.prototype);
```

#### TL;DR

There are basically four ways to extend map (some from answers/comments below):

1. Add methods to Map.prototype (shame on you).
2. Factory/constructor makes objects with an internal Map instance that you delegate to
3. Mixin fn that copies properties onto Maps:

```
function Foo(){this.bar = 'boo!'}
var baz = new Map();
Foo.call(baz);
baz.bar; //yields 'boo!'
baz.set('5', 5).get('5'); //yields 5
```

Or just wait for ES 6 classes to hit the platform(s) you care about

Comment: Have you tried setting `Foo.prototype` to `Object.create(Map.prototype)`? Have you tried ES6 subclassing, which the spec explicitly says should work?

Comment: Throws same type Error.

Comment: There is no way to "inherit" from an ES6 class the "traditional" way (`Object.crate(Map.prototype)` + `Map.call(this)`) because class constructors cannot be called without `new`. This will likely change in ES7 which will introduce a new concept for calling functions.

Comment: ^ See the quoted part in the first message here: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-to-fix-the-class-keyword-brendan-eich (so, maybe it's just for classes, not functions or objects in general)

Comment: @Pointy I'm trying to use an augmented Map now. ES 6 classes haven't been implemented yet in V8.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks I'm reading the referenced gist right now.

Comment: Subclassing of built-ins is in V8 now, and will be available in Chrome 42 along with classes.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg thank you, I just got the latest canary. Now to wait for it to hit Node...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In V8 environments this throws an Error "Map constructor not called with 'new'". Why?

Because new ES6 classes (including builtin ones) are supposed to be only constructable with `new`.

> SpiderMonkey gets this 'right'

Not exactly. [The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-map-constructor) explicitly says

> *`Map` is not intended to be called as a function and will throw an exception when called in that manner.*

> Wishing to subclass Map

Yes, that's the appropriate thing:

> *The `Map` constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value in an `extends` clause of a `class` definition. Subclass constructors that intend to inherit the specified `Map` behaviour must include a `super` call to the Map constructor to create and initialize the subclass instance with the internal state necessary to support the `Map.prototype` built-in methods.*

So you'll want to use

```
class Foo extends Map {
    // default constructor
}
var bar = new Foo();
bar.set('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: Only problem with that is that V8 doesn't implement classes yet. I'm looking for a polyfill I can use now if I can find it.

Comment: @JaredSmith: How about creating a wrapper around `Map` instead of extending it then? You have to define the same API and delegate to the internal Map instance, but the API is not that big.

Comment: @JaredSmith: I don't think there's a solution then. Maybe you can do something with `Proxy`s to emulate subclassing behaviour.

Comment: Proxy isn't in V8 yet, think I'll have to go with @Felix Kling's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it doesn't really 'work' in FF, since FF also allows to create maps simply by calling `Map()`.

However, according to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ we do not have compatibility for subclassing in modern browser (fascinating enough, IE has some support here).

**tl;dr** V8/SpiderMonkey are not fully ES6 compatible yet.

Comment: Right. I'm looking for a polyfill I can use now, since Maps have been implemented

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
function Foo() {
    return new (Map.bind(this, [].slice.call(arguments)));
}

var bar = new Foo();
```

Comment: And what purpose of this? `bar` will not have prototype of `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this in 2018:

```
import ES6Map from 'es6-map/polyfill'

class MyMap extends ES6Map {
  constructor () {
    super()
  }
}
```