# Create a class extending from ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Trying to get away with custom get/set functionality on ES6 Maps. Currently using [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) to transpile my code to ES5.

`Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m`

```
class MyMap extends Map {
    get(key) {
        if (!this.has(key)) { throw new Error(...); }
        return super.get(key);
    }

    set(key) {
        if (this.has(key)) { throw new Error(...); }
        return super.set(key);
    }
}
```

Not sure if I just got the syntax wrong or I'm missing an implementation of some sort. But I get the following error:

> Method Map.prototype.forEach called on incompatible reciever

Comment: I just get `Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`

Comment: And I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`. Chrome might not really support extending built-in classes yet.

Comment: Yup, in io.js I am able to compile it without any errors (though I had to have `"use strict"` at the top)

Comment: @FelixKling And of course I forgot to mention that I'm using babel to transpile...

Comment: Ah... I don't think it's possible to have "ES5 classes" extend built-in ES6 classes, because it requires to call the parent constructor in a way that is not allowed by ES6 classes. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28900954/218196

Comment: Crap I was afraid of that... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Babel explictly states they do not support extending built-in classes. See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/#classes. The reasons are not quite as simple as "limitations in ES5", however, since `Map` is not an ES5 feature to begin with. It appears that implementations of Map do not support basic patterns such as

```
Map.prototype.set.call(mymap, 'key', 1);
```

which is essentially what Babel generates in this case. The problem is that implementations of Map including V8 are overly restrictive and check that the `this` in the `Map.set.call` call is precisely a Map, rather than having Map in its prototype chain.

Same applies to Promise.

Comment: So you have to re-implement every method of Map as a proxy to an internal Map?! That seems highly screwy. Seems the Babel folks must not actually use Maps. ┻━┻ ︵ ლ(⌒-⌒ლ)

Comment: You could implement your own methods such as `guardedSet` and guardedGet` on the `Map` prototype.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the good old way:

```
function ExtendedMap(iterable = []) {
  if (!(this instanceof ExtendedMap)) {
    throw new TypeError("Constructor ExtendedMap requires 'new'");
  }

  const self = (Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === Map.prototype) 
    ? this 
    : new Map(iterable);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(self, ExtendedMap.prototype);

  // Do your magic with `self`...

  return self;
}

util.inherits(ExtendedMap, Map);
Object.setPrototypeOf(ExtendedMap, Map);

ExtendedMap.prototype.foo = function foo() {
  return this.get('foo');
}
```

Then use `new` as usual:

```
const exMap = new ExtendedMap([['foo', 'bar']]);
exMap instanceof ExtendedMap; // true
exMap.foo(); // "bar"
```

Notice that the `ExtendedMap` constructor ignore any `this` binding that isn't a `Map`.

See also [How to extend a Promise](https://gist.github.com/domenic/8ed6048b187ee8f2ec75).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can compose the Map() class within your MapWrapper object and expose your own API. The notion of object Composition was not of much in use 5 yrs ago and so, the question and answers were tied to and tangled with Inheritance.

Comment: Hey Murali! Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure what you mean by that? Like using composition within the class? (ie MyClass has some internal map obj that I can use?) 
I haven't run into this problem as I don't really think the side effects are a good idea anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Yup, until [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) arrive in full force the only way to achieve what you were trying to do is to shadow the built-in methods on the Map/Set, etc. yourself.

For instance, if you have your map like so:

```
var myMap = new Map([ ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']])
```

You'd have to have some wrapper to pass it into to add the built-in methods, for instance for get/set:

```
function proxify(obj){
    var $fnMapGet = function(key){
        console.log('%cmap get', 'color:limegreen', 'key:', key)
        if(!Map.prototype.has.call(this, key)){
            throw(new Error('No such key: '+ key))
        } else {
            return Map.prototype.get.call(this, key)
        }
    }
    var $fnMapSet = function(key, value){
        console.log('%cmap set', 'color:tomato', 'key:', key, 'value:', value)
        if(Map.prototype.has.call(this, key)){
            throw(new Error('key is already defined: ' + key))
        } else {
            if(Map.prototype.get.call(this, key) == value){
                console.log('%cmap set', 'color:tomato', '*no change')
                return this
            }
            return Map.prototype.set.call(this, key, value)
        }
    }

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'get', {
        get(){
            return $fnMapGet
        }
    })
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'set', {
        get(){
            return $fnMapSet
        }
    })

    return obj
}
```

So then:

```
proxify(myMap)

myMap.get('key1') // <= "value1"
myMap.get('key2') // <= "value2"
myMap.get('key3') // <= Uncaught Error: No such key: key3
myMap.set('key3', 'value3') // <= Map {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3"}
myMap.set('key3', 'another value3') // <= Uncaught Error: key is already defined: key3
```

That would add the ability to do your own custom set/get on the map, not nearly as nice as subclassing Map nor as straightforward as es6 proxies but it at least it works.

The full code snippet running below:

```js
var myMap = new Map([ ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']])

function proxify(obj){
 var $fnMapGet = function(key){
  console.log('get key:', key)
  if(!Map.prototype.has.call(this, key)){
   throw(new Error('No such key: '+ key))
  } else {
   return Map.prototype.get.call(this, key)
  }
 }
 var $fnMapSet = function(key, value){
  console.log('set key:', key, 'value:', value)
  if(Map.prototype.has.call(this, key)){
   throw(new Error('key is already defined: ' + key))
  } else {
   if(Map.prototype.get.call(this, key) == value){
    console.log('*no change')
    return this
   }
   return Map.prototype.set.call(this, key, value)
  }
 }

 Object.defineProperty(obj, 'get', {
  get(){
   return $fnMapGet
  }
 })
 Object.defineProperty(obj, 'set', {
  get(){
   return $fnMapSet
  }
 })

 return obj
}

proxify(myMap)
myMap.get('key1')
myMap.get('key2')
try {
  myMap.get('key3')
} catch(ex){
  console.warn('error:', ex.message)
}
myMap.set('key3', 'value3')
try {
  myMap.set('key3', 'another value3')
} catch(ex){
  console.warn('error:', ex.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Babel doesn't support it. The odd thing is, you can run the following in your console:

```
clear();

var Store = function Store(data) {
    // var _map = new Map(data);
    this.get = function get(key) {
        console.log('#get', key);
        return S.prototype.get.call(S.prototype, key);  // or return _map.get(key);
    };
    this.set = function set(key, value) {
        S.prototype.set.call(S.prototype, key, value);  // or _map.set(key, value);
        return this;
    };
};
Store.prototype = new Map();  // we could just wrap new Map() in our constructor instead

var s = new Store();

s.set('a', 1);
s.get('a');
```

However, running the following with Babel is useless:

```
class Store extends Map {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        return this;
    }
}
```

You'll throw an error trying to call `(new Store(['a','1'])).get('a')`. This horrifies me that something as important as `Map` would be utterly dismissed by the folks at Babel.

Here's what I recommend. **What I've been doing for several years is** *create an JavaScript Class which you can tote around with you to any gig or project. Call it "`Dictionary`", and if your environment supports `Map` and you need a map, just wrap `Map` -- for performance sake. If you need to inherit from `Map`, inherit from `Dictionary`*. I actually have my own private repo with various algorithms & data-structures that I bring everywhere I go, but you can also find public repos that accomplish the same thing. Kind of a pain, but that way you're not relying 100% on the same thing for every framework & environment.