# Remove elements from inside Array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, prototype-pattern

I'm trying to extend js native array inside angular service to add some extra features without prototyping global objects.

```
app.factory('Collection', function($http, $q) {
    var Collection = function(arr) {
        this.key = 'id';
        this._last = 0;
        this._first = 77777777; //just big number.
        this.append(arr);
    }
    Collection.prototype = new Array;
    Collection.prototype.orderBy = function(n, reverse) {
        if (reverse) {
            this.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b[n] - a[n];
            })
        } else {
            this.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a[n] - b[n];
            })
        }
    }
    Collection.prototype.spliceBy = function(key, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i][key] !== val) {
                this.splice(i, 1); ///THIS NEVER HAPPENS !!
                console.log('removed ' + i + ' from ', this);
            }
        }
    }
    Collection.prototype.subset = function(key, val) {
        return this.filter(function(v) {
            return (v[key] === val);
        });
    }
    Collection.prototype.add = function(obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i][this.key] > this._last) {
                this._last = this[i][this.key];
            }
            if (this[i][this.key] < this._first) {
                this._first = this[i][this.key];
            }
            if (this[i][this.key] === data[this.key]) {
                if (override) {
                    this[i] = data;
                    console.log('updated uniquePush');
                }
                return i;
                break;
            }
        }
        var id = this.push(data) - 1;
        data._index = id;
        return id;
    }
    return collection
});
```

This is working fine except for the `spliceBy` function.
I need to filter out elements that does not have value = x;
For example in my controller

```
.controller(function($scope,Collection){

$scope.posts = new Collection;

$scope.posts.add({id:1,type:'post'});
$scope.posts.add({id:2,type:'comment'});

//Collection is now [{id:1,type:post},{id:2,type:comment}];

//i want to remove all comments from array
$scope.posts.spliceBy('type','comment');

});
```

Yet nothing happens when calling spliceBy :*(

Comment: This doesnt look right `Collection.prototype = new Array;`. You cannot do that in ES5. You can subclass arrays in ES6 though.

Comment: @elclanrs  not sure about that but its working fine in all my browsers and cordova apps :-)

Comment: If its working fine why did you post the question? Arrays are not subclassable except in the most recent versions of Chrome/Edge (no FF yet) and even the require use of (native) class syntax. The only (and I mean only) other ways to make it work are to write a wrapper class with an internal array instance that it delegates to as necessary or to monkey-patch Array.prototype. As soon as you try to call a native array method (e.g. splice, reduce, shift) on your 'subclass' it will fail.

Comment: I know, because I tried to do the same thing with Maps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900954/why-isnt-map-subclassable-in-chrome-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spliceBy` function will not work if you have two elements to remove in a row, because splice is updating the indexes from i to array.length. Try this instead:

```
Collection.prototype.spliceBy = function(key, val) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i][key] !== val) {
            this.splice(i, 1); ///THIS NEVER HAPPENS !!
            console.log('removed ' + i + ' from ', this);
        }
    }
}
```